# Self-Capacitance of Disc

Tags: electromagnetism, capacitance

I was reading a paper today modeling capacitances, and came across self-capacitance of a disc. After skimming google, it looks like this is defined as "the capacitance between the object itself, and infinity." There are examples online of the self capacitance of a hollow conducting sphere, but this is very straight forward since you simply integrate from the radius $R$ to infinity and out comes the self capacitance.

The paper says the self-capacitance between 2D disc-shape object and infinity is $C_0 = 8 \epsilon_0 R$. This is also confirmed by wolfram http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=self+capacitance&x=0&y=0.

I attempted to calculate this myself. I followed the derivation of an electric field at a distance $x$ from the center of a disc at this page http://www.physics.udel.edu/~watson/phys208/exercises/kevan/efield1.html to get a result of
$$E_x = \frac{Q}{2\pi \epsilon_0 R^2} \left(1 - \frac{x}{(x^2 + R^2)^{1/2}}\right)$$

I took it the rest of the way myself, calculating the potential. I used
$$V = -\int E \cdot dx$$
where by mathematica
$$\int_0^{\infty} \left(1 - \frac{x}{(x^2 + R^2)^{1/2}}\right) dx = R$$

Thus for the capacitance I get the result

$$C = \frac{Q}{V}$$
$$C = -2\pi \epsilon_0 R$$

So obviously the negative shouldn't be there, which I'm less worried about, but the factors aren't even close to correct. Somehow I'm missing a $4/\pi$

Anybody see anything wrong with my approach here? Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of "Capacitance of a single charged plate?" http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/187139

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this...one of the answers literally goes through exactly what I was hoping for =).

Comment: The minus sign is because your integral limits are the wrong way round?

Comment: Yeah I figured that one out shortly after posting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are referring to the formula for capacitance of a uniformly charged disk.
A metal disk has uniform potential, but NOT uniform charge: the charge
density at the periphery of the disk is higher than at the center.

Comment: Thanks, good answer. I was able to derive once I accounted for this.