# What would be the capacitance of a shorted parallel plate capacitor?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, capacitance, voltage

What would be the capacitance of a shorted parallel plate capacitor?

I have three answers:

Answer 1: Undefined; Because $C=Q/V$ and since $Q=0; V=0 $ Capacitence becomes $0/0$

Answer 2: Infinite; Because $C=A\epsilon/d$ and here $d=0$

Answer 3: Some definite value; Because when shorted my parallel plate capacitor becomes a single conductor of some shape and [Capacitance of a single charged plate?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/187154/447) is some finite value.  One could say but your shorted is not charged. True, but the final expression for capacitance contains neither $Q$ nor $V$. In fact, capacitance depends on the medium and geometrical parameters of the capacitor.

Which one of the above is right? I'm confused.

**EDIT:** Kindly also tell me why my other answers are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Capacitance is, in a sense, a physical property of the device, and doesn't depend on the amount of charge on the device.  This means that answer 2 is the most correct response, but note that the plate separation cannot be zero because there is a dielectric material (an insulator) in between the plates.  If plate separation is zero, the plates short against each other, and you no longer have a capacitor ... you have two thin and wide conductors.