# Calculating the self capacitance of a rectangular electrode with a dielectric on one side

Tags: capacitance

I am trying to derive an expression for the capacitance of a rectangular electrode with a dielectric material of thickness $t$ and relative permittivity $\epsilon_r$ in contact with one side, sized identically to the rectangular electrode and congruent with it.

Since I couldn't find an expression for the self capacitance of a rectangular electrode, I simplified to a circular electrode with radius $r$ where

$C_{intrinsic} = 8 \epsilon_0 r$

as per [this PSE answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/187139/capacitance-of-a-single-charged-plate) and then modeled the region with the dielectric material as a parallel plate capacitor in series with this self capacitance. For this parallel plate capacitor

$C_{additional} = {\epsilon_0 \epsilon_r \pi r^2  \over t}$

so by my logic

$C_{total} = {1 \over {1 \over C_{instrinsic}} + {1 \over C_{additional}}} = ({ {1 \over 8 \epsilon_0 r} + {t \over \epsilon_0 \epsilon_r \pi r^2} })^{-1} = ({\pi r \epsilon_r \over 8 \epsilon_0 \epsilon_r \pi r^2} + {8t \over 8 \epsilon_0 \epsilon_r \pi r^2})^{-1} = {8 \epsilon_0 \epsilon_r \pi r^2 \over \pi r \epsilon_r + 8t }  $

My gut feeling is that this result is not correct - and by extension my modeling is not correct. Both instinctively and empirically, the total capacitance should increase when an additional dielectric with $\epsilon_r > 1$ is introduced, yet my derived expression does not guarantee this. An increase in total capacitance seems to depend on the size of the electrode, the relative permittivity and the material thickness, which appears to be incorrect.

What am I doing wrong? And further to my original intent, is it possible to derive such an expression for this capacitance for rectangular (and other non-circular) electrode shapes?